# DataGridView prevent auto increasing of id bound column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a database with id (identity) column. This column is bound to my DataGridView (WindowsForms). Whenever I add a row to DataGridView (it's not yet added to database, just to DataGridView), number in this column is increasing by one. Extremely annoying behaviour and I don't know how to stop it?

I am not using EF or antyhing similar. Just columns in DataGridView (not automatically generated, but user defined columns - AutoGenerateColumns is switched off), added to DataGridView and with each column set the DataPropertyName.

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: It's just a DataGridView, with columns added to it. What code do you want to see?

Comment: @user867703 do you mean your column is filled with ordinal numbers automatically? sounds strange, because at least that's not the default behavior of any column, also note that the grid you use may be some kind of custom grid view. Simply you try adding a new gridview to a new form and test it now, you won't surely see that problem.

Comment: @KingKing I've did just like you've said - but this autogenerating of id's is happening again. And, my grid is not custom DataGridView. Just regular one, I am populating it through typed datasets. The only thing that I set in my column is DataPropertyName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to prevent DataGridView from auto increasing id. But, I could change any value in DataGridView now, with the DataSource being bound to BindingList instead of DataTable, as before (each ComboBoxItem must implement INotifyPropertyChanged).

```
private void initializeDgvNotesDataSource()
{            
    List<ComboBoxItem> list = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
    BindingList<ComboBoxItem> bindingList = new BindingList<ComboBoxItem>(list);
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;
    dgvNotes.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code, but did you try to do this:

```
datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

and make a button for adding the rows , and add it with

```
datagridview1.Rows.Add(-1,..,...);
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking at first adding rows with button click and some text boxes. But I've found that more complicated for users, so I am doing everything through data grid view directly. Only saving of inserted rows (they are marked at first for saving) is done by pressing one button.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your **integer** type id column as **string** before binding to grid. like
select  **CAST(ID as varchar(100))** as from yourtablename.

You can also set the default value to identify the new record.

[image: 1]

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm just running into the "feature" of the first column auto incrementing. I remember now why I've avoided the datagridview in the past in windows desktop apps (it's a terrible tool for editing - only good for display)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide the column?

```
dgvMyDataGridView.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: I need Id column. For rows not yet in DB I gave ID of -1. So hiding the column wouldn't change anything and Id would still get automatically increased.

Comment: Ok,what value do you want in "Id" column? -1? You can set it yourself on "UserAddedRow" event of the DataGridView:
`dgvMyDataGridView["Id", e.Row.Index].Value = -1`

Comment: I am already doing this. But the problem is when I step into the last row (UserAddedRow is not triggered until I press some key) - then this ID is created. If I exit out of the DataGridView than, I have a wrong ID auto generated and I want to prevent DataGridView of doing this.

Comment: Humm...use the `RowEnter` event,when a user enters in a Row,verify if its the last one,if it is change de "Id" value to "-1" (didn't tried this one)

Comment: It's the truth that RowEnter event is triggered before CellBeginEdit event (I have CellBeginEdit already in code). I've tried to set id through RowEnter, but then I was receiving error after error that id column is read only. This is strange, because I change id later in my other method.

Comment: Try to unbound the column,remove the DataPropertyName from "Id"

Comment: But how will I then get Id's from database? You know, I need Id's for updating and deleting rows.

Comment: Depends on how you fill your DataGridView.
If you unbound that column you have to control it by code.

Comment: I guess in that case I'll had to fill all columns by code. Perhaps more typing, but on the long run more robust solution.